# Better method to count an associated object off a group of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would one count the number of Items that are tickets in the following scenario? The ticket column lives in the Items table.

I'm trying to grab a group of redemptions, and then count the number of items that are 'tickets' for that group of redemptions.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :redemptions

class Redemption < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
```

```
#This method works, but is there a much better way?

def tickets_sold
        my_tickets_sold = 0
        @redemptions = Redemption.where(state: "valid")
        redemptions.each do |redemption|
            if redemption.item.ticket == true
                my_tickets_sold = my_tickets_sold + 1
            end
        end
        my_tickets_sold
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it in better way, you can use below of the 3 ways

1) Add associans for getting records of sold tickets

```
has_many    :sold_tickets, -> { left_outer_joins(:item).where("state = 'valid' AND items.ticket = true ") }
```

2) Add scope for fetching count of sold tickets

```
  scope :sold_tickets_count, -> { left_outer_joins(:item).where("state = 'valid' AND items.ticket = true ").count }
```

3) Add instance method in model for fetching count of sold tickets

```
def sold_tickets_count
   left_outer_joins(:item).where("state = 'valid' AND items.ticket = true ").count
end
```

Comment: Thanks @vishal! The joins worked. I went ahead and used this in my case: ```@redemptions.joins(:item).where("state = 'valid' AND items.ticket = true ").count```

Comment: @TannerBrandt If you don't mind please also upvote this answer, which will help other users who is facing the same issue